# gb4e: vertical alignment when using brackets

Tags: spacing, gb4e

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe} 
    \ex
    \gll m-itoetra \lb{PP, ADJC}amin' ilay trano mena] izahay. \\
    \textsc{pres-}live \qquad \qquad in that house red \textsc{1pl.exclusive.nom} \\
    \glt `We live in that red house.'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Hi, I am trying to align "amin'" and "in" vertically. I've tried \qquad, but is there any other way I can vertically align them (preferably automatically)? I thought about alignment to the right, but I couldn't find anything about it in the manual. Thank you for your help in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply insert an empty atom `{}` that will go under `\lb{PP, ADJC}` and insert a space after the latter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \gll m-itoetra \lb{PP, ADJC} amin' ilay trano mena] izahay. \\
    \textsc{pres-}live {} in that house red \textsc{1pl.exclusive.nom} \\
    \glt `We live in that red house.'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

karlkoeller's suggestion of using `{}` in the gloss line is what you'd have to do in `gb4e`. For the sake of completeness, I thought I'd mention that the [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package provides a `\nogloss{}` command for material that appears in the target language line but doesn't have a corresponding gloss. This way you don't have to remember to put empty elements in the gloss line.

`expex` allows you to remove the horizontal space between the `\nogloss{}` material and the next word using `@`, which is great for non-annotated brackets so that there's no space but the gloss is still aligned with the word and not the bracket (I added one in the example below to mark the DP).

In my opinion, the default interword space is too much to have between the bracket annotation and the next word (this is what happens in `gb4e`). I prefer a normal single space, so in the example below I do that by using the `@` to remove the interword space and then put a normal single space at the end of the `\lb` definition. In `gb4e` you would have to use something like `\hspace*{-0.5ex}amin'` if you wanted to reduce the interword space.

**Example:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times} % the Computer Modern brackets are too thin to see these effects clearly
\usepackage{amsmath} % to allow use of \text{} command
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{%
    everygla=, % gla line will be in normal roman font
    aboveglftskip=-0.2ex % removes extra vertical space between gloss line and free translation line
}

\newcommand{\gloss}[1]{`#1'} % so that you don't have to correctly type `' each time
\newcommand{\lb}[1]{$\text{[}_{\text{#1}}$ } % for annotated left brackets; I put a space after the annotation so it's not run directly into the next word

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl
    \gla m-itoetra \nogloss{\lb{\textsc{PP,ADJC}}} @ amin' \nogloss{[} @ ilay trano mena]] izahay. // % @ removes the interword space between the non-glossed material and the next word (the \lb{} macro adds in a single space)
    \glb \textsc{prs-}live in that house red \textsc{1pl.excl.nom} //
    \glft \gloss{We live in that red house.} //
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```