# Square brackets and subscript in expex glossing

Tags: linguistics, expex

I'm new to Latex and trying to figure out how to do the following thing with expex: I would like to use square bracket as well as a **subscripted** word such as 'NP' in the transcription line, where everything else is italic and glossed. Something like this (with the NP subscripted):

[*my       dog*]NP *ate       me*.

1SG.POSS   dog     eat.PST   1SG.ACC

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6):

The `expex` package provides a `\nogloss` macro to exempt certain elements from being counted as in the gloss.  I've made two bracketing macros to create upright brackets: `\lb` creates an upright left bracket, and `\rb{XP}` creates an upright right bracket with a label "XP".

Unfortunately, due to the way `expex` is written, you can't include the `\nogloss` command inside the `\lb` and `\rb` macros, so they need to be used explicitly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % This package not needed for > 2015 distributions 
\usepackage{expex}

\newcommand{\lb}{\upshape[}
\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\upshape]\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}
\ex
\begingl
  \gla \nogloss{\lb}  Mon ami \nogloss{\rb{NP}}     est  \nogloss{\lb} grand \nogloss{\rb{AP}}//
  \glb my friend is tall//
  \glft `My friend is tall'//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1. This answer is great. @user73020, if you want to know to fine-tune the horizontal spacing of the brackets, take a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229544/42880.

Comment: @balivon, one thing to be aware of is that `\nogloss` doesn't work right if it's the first thing on the `\gla` line and there's an `\ljudge` for the grammaticality judgment marker (regardless of whether there's a space between `\ljudge{*}` and `\nogloss` or not). In that case, I surround the initial bracket(s) with `{}` instead of `\nogloss{}` and put an empty `{}` at the beginning of the `\glb` line to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `philex` with `fixltx2e`, but I think, that you can combine it with your `expex` code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{philex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\lb{ex2}{\gll [my dog]\textsubscript{NP} ate me.\\
1\textsc{sg}.\textsc{poss} dog eat.\textsc{pst} 1\textsc{sg}.\textsc{acc}\\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, since your code doesn't actually use the `expex` package.