# ExPex gloss formating

Tags: formatting, expex, gloss

I'm using the `expex` packages for my glossing exemples and it's working great but:

I want my `\gla` exemple to be in typewriter format (`\tt`). And then I want to gloss only some parts of my exemple (the rest is irrelevant) but when I put `\nogloss` command the text inside goes back to roman format. And what I want is to have all the `\gla` line to  be in typewriter font.

So this is my exemple :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcommand{\pt}{\textsc{2sg.fam}~}
\begin{document}
\pex[labeltype=numeric,everygla=\tt]
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{HEN :} \underline{t'as} encore besoin d'argent/ //
\glb \pt'avoir-\pt~ //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{ANT : non j'ai rencontré quelqu'un que j'aime alors je voulais} \underline{te} la présenter //
\glb \pt~ //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{HEN : ouais je vois oui encore une de} \underline{tes} mannequins sans cervelle//
\glb \pt~ //
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

How can I make LaTeX obey my orders? haha :) Pretty please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation

Your orders are being obeyed; it's just that `\nogloss{}` doesn't work the way you think it does. The formatting you specify in `everygla` doesn't apply to material within `\nogloss{}` (although this isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation). This is because `expex` is designed primarily to be used for interlinear glossing where every word is glossed, so the material in `\nogloss{}` is typically punctuation (e.g., brackets, ellipses, etc.) or silent elements (e.g., traces, gaps, operators, etc.). These punctuation marks and silent elements are usually formatted differently from the normal text: even if you keep the default italics formatting of the `gla` line, you wouldn't want a labeled bracket like [<sub>NP</sub> to be in italics, so `\nogloss{}` doesn't pay attention to `everygla`.

### Solutions

Here are three solutions for your case.

Note that I removed the `~` that you had both within and after your `\pt` command because it added unnecessary spacing. Feel free to add that back in if you actually wanted that space. I also changed the [deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/42880) `\tt` to `\ttfamily` (`expex` often uses the obsolete font commands in its defaults and documentation, but you shouldn't).

#### Solution 1

Put `\ttfamily` within `\nogloss`. You might imagine that you could define a new command like `\newcommand{\nogl}[1]{\nogloss{\ttfamily #1}}`, but unfortunately [it doesn't work to put `\nogloss` inside a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230012/42880).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcommand{\pt}{\textsc{2sg.fam}}
\begin{document}

\pex[labeltype=numeric,everygla=\ttfamily]
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{\ttfamily HEN : } \underline{t'as} encore besoin d'argent/ //
\glb \pt'avoir-\pt //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{\ttfamily ANT : non j'ai rencontré quelqu'un que j'aime alors je voulais} \underline{te} la présenter //
\glb \pt //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla \nogloss{\ttfamily HEN : ouais je vois oui encore une de} \underline{tes} mannequins sans cervelle//
\glb \pt //
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

#### Solution 2

Surround your non-glossed material in `{}` and add a corresponding `{}` to the `glb` line. This is how we had to do this before `\nogloss{}` became available in `expex` version 5.0. See the discussion in section 9.2.3 of the documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcommand{\pt}{\textsc{2sg.fam}}
\begin{document}
\pex[labeltype=numeric,everygla=\ttfamily] % I changed the deprecated \tt to \ttfamily
\a
\begingl
\gla {HEN : } \underline{t'as} encore besoin d'argent/ //
\glb {} \pt'avoir-\pt //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla {ANT : non j'ai rencontré quelqu'un que j'aime alors je voulais} \underline{te} la présenter //
\glb {} \pt //
\endgl
\a
\begingl
\gla {HEN : ouais je vois oui encore une de} \underline{tes} mannequins sans cervelle//
\glb {} \pt //
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

#### Solution 3

Use the new `nlevel` glossing style (see section 10 of the documentation). The `[]` that correspond to the `glb` line are required (p. 44), but you don't have to put one on every word, only on every `glword`. So you can just break your lines up into three `glword`s: the first being all the words before your glossed word, the second being the glossed word, and the third being all the words after your glossed word.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcommand{\pt}{\textsc{2sg.fam}}

\begin{document}

\pex[labeltype=numeric,glstyle=nlevel,glneveryline={\ttfamily}]
\a \begingl HEN :[] \underline{t'as}[\pt'avoir-\pt] encore besoin d'argent/[] \endgl % There are three sets of [], dividing the line into three glwords, only one of which is actually glossed.
\a \begingl ANT : non j'ai rencontré quelqu'un que j'aime alors je voulais[] \underline{te}[\pt] la présenter[] \endgl
\a \begingl HEN : ouais je vois oui encore une de[] \underline{tes}[\pt] mannequins sans cervelle[] \endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! thank you VERY much Jason!:) I knew there was a simple solution to that! :)